# Java Maven project won't import plugin

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jar, maven-plugin

I have a Maven project in intelliJ community edition, and I'm trying to package everything in a jar file that I can execute. I've been following tutorials online and have tried adding several plugins to the pom.xml file.
However they're all showing in red with the following error messages:

```
Plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:' not found 
Plugin 'maven-assembly-plugin:' not found 
Plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:' not found
```

I've tried Invalidating and Restarting caches. Ive enabled the use plugin registry option within the Maven settings. I've also tried reloading the maven project multiple times with no success.
Is there a solution to this? or any other way I can create an executable jar from the project.

FYI I'm also on Mac if that matters.

```
    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation=
                                                     "org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>Your_main_class_here</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <finalName>ServiceCreate</finalName>
                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.svt.optimoo.App</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: Have you tried to put a version tag with current (or not so current) version numbers in the plugins?

Comment: Ahh I missed that. Yes it works now, thank you.